# Email Location Type in Scheduled Reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I am wondering if anyone has started work of made an extension to enable the selection of the location type to send the email to in the scheduled reminders?

I think by default the primary email adres is used but we have some use cases where we want to use work or home email for the reminder.

I hope some other people share the wish to develop this or can attribute a starting point to code this.

Regards,
Richard